# Rails, Nested resource controller generates non-restful url on render edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

I'm still somewhat new to rails but I'm seeing strange behavior and wondering if this is convention or if I've done something incorrectly.

I have the following nested resources:

```
resources :accounts do
  resources :users
end
```

And they are generating standard restful urls ( host.com/accounts/my-account-name/users/33/edit), except when an UPDATE to a user fails (due to validation for example). Then it generates a url like host.com/accounts/22/users/22, or essentially host.com/accounts/:user_id/users/:user_id

What is going on here? The application still will update the user but I don't understand why this works. Any help or understanding is appreciated.

The Users controller is below:

```
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.update(user_params)
      format.html{
        redirect_to account_users_path(@user.account),
                    notice: 'User was successfully updated.'
      }
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
    end
  end
end
```

Here's my form:

```
.card
        .header Edit User
        .content
          = form_for(@user, url: account_user_path(@user), html: {class: 'form-horizontal'}) do |f|
            .content
              - if @user.errors.any?
                .alert.alert-danger
                  h4 = "#{pluralize(@user.errors.count, 'error')} prohibited the user from being saved."
                  == @user.errors.full_messages.map{|msg| content_tag(:li, msg)}.join
              .form-group
                = f.label :name, class: 'control-label col-lg-2'
                .col-lg-10
                  = f.text_field :name, {placeholder: 'Name', autofocus: true,class: 'form-control'}
              .form-group
                = f.label :email, class: 'control-label col-lg-2'
                .col-lg-10
                  = f.email_field :email, {placeholder: 'Email', class: 'form-control'}
              .form-group
                = label_tag "user[role]", "Role", class: 'control-label col-lg-2'
                .col-lg-10
                  = select_tag "user[role]", options_for_select(@choices,@user.roles.first.name), class:'form-control'
            .footer style ="height: 55px;"
              span.pull-left
                = link_to 'Cancel', account_users_path, class: 'btn btn-primary btn-warning'
              span.pull-right
                =f.submit "Save", class: 'btn btn-primary'
            .footer style ="height: 55px;"
              - if current_user.has_role?(:owner, current_account)
                span.pull-right
                  = link_to 'Delete', account_user_path(@user), {method: :delete, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'},
                          class: 'btn btn-danger'} unless @user.id == current_user.id
```

Comment: how are your `accounts` and `users` table associated?

Comment: can we see your form ?

Comment: `host.com/accounts/:account_id/users/:user_id ` your are nesting multiple users under one account. In your example Account with ID 22 has an User with ID 22. But there might also be an Account with ID 2 having Users with ID 123, 23, 245 ...

Comment: @Gabbar, account has_many :users, and user belongs_to :account.

Comment: @Snake, just added my form, and I think I see the problem. Is it because the form_for url is only being passed the user and needs the account too?

Comment: @Snake, yep, that fixed it. I still don't understand why it worked without that change though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what are trying to ask, so far as i understand your nested routes works fine :- 
let me explain

when you will run `rake routes | grep users`

```
get   'accounts/my-account-name/users/:user_id/edit',to: 'users#edit'
put   'accounts/:account_id/users/:user_id', to: 'users#update'
patch 'accounts/:account_id/users/:user_id', to: 'users#update'
```

so here for your every action you would need to pass `account_id` with url as well as at controller you would need to set `@account` before any action. you can do this as at `users controller`

```
before_action: get_account
private
  def get_account
    @account = Account.find(params[:id])
  end
```

and for your `edit_form` pass first argument as `account` object and `user` object and also specify method type for update action

```
= form_for(@user, url: account_user_path(@account,@user), html: {class: 'form-horizontal', method: :patch}) do |f|
```

Comment: the problem was in my form. I wasn't passing in the account instance variable along with the user instance variable.

Comment: @Austin the exactly i explained above.  could you accept/upvote my answer if my explaination helped you